# Change SVG fill parameter with different color on different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jquery-svg

Hove I change SVG fill parameter depending on which page class i am.

For example:
If I'm on the front page that has a class `.home-page` I want to fill my parameter with `#000000`.

And when I on contact page that has a class .contact-page I want to fill my parameter with `#ffffff`.

```
<rect x="-4.79" y="-5.11" clip-path="url(#SVGID_6_)" fill="#000000" width="37" height="37.03"/>
```

link: http://codepen.io/NGrdanjski/pen/jAKEPJ

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `fill` property with css

```css
body {
  background:#ddd;
}

.contact-page .circle {
  fill:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="logo" x="0" y="0" width="40" height="82" viewBox="0 0 28 60" enable-background="new 0 0 28 60" xml:space="preserve">
  <g enable-background="new    ">
    <defs>
      <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="0.21" y="-0.11" width="27" height="60"/>
    </defs>
    <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
      <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_" overflow="visible"/>
    </clipPath>
    <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)">
      <defs>
        <ellipse id="SVGID_3_" cx="13.71" cy="13.41" rx="13.5" ry="13.52"/>
      </defs>
      <clipPath id="SVGID_4_">
        <use xlink:href="#SVGID_3_" overflow="visible"/>
      </clipPath>
      <g clip-path="url(#SVGID_4_)">
        <defs>
          <rect id="SVGID_5_" x="0.21" y="-0.11" width="27" height="60"/>
        </defs>
        <clipPath id="SVGID_6_">
          <use xlink:href="#SVGID_5_" overflow="visible"/>
        </clipPath>
        <rect class="circle" x="-4.79" y="-5.11" clip-path="url(#SVGID_6_)" fill="#000000" width="37" height="37.03"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
</div>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('div').classList.toggle('contact-page')">Toggle .contact-page</button>
```

http://jsbin.com/moxezu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this.

```css
.homepage .mycircle
{
  fill: red;
}

.otherpage .mycircle
{
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage">
  <svg>
    <circle class="mycircle" cx="75" cy="75" r="75"/>
  </svg>
</div>


<div class="otherpage">
  <svg>
    <circle class="mycircle" cx="75" cy="75" r="75"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```